# Efeito no NavBar similar ao do Twitter

Tags: javascript, css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo efetuar este efeito no navbar? O mesmo está presente no Twitter.

Quando a página está na home, fica uma barra azul no nome da página na navbar, o mesmo se aplica às outras páginas;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra que a bordar não afete os demais elementos você pode fazer o uso do `box-sizing: border-box;` se for utilizar uma altura fixa e se quiser o efeito animado (que geralmente estão nos perfis) use `transition:` combinado com `border-bottom-width:`

Assim:

```css
/*Remove margens da página*/
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*sombra no navbar*/
.navbar {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

/*coloca os links lado a lado*/
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 46px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 0 #f00 solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: border-bottom-width .2s;
}

/*faz com que o navbar acompanhe a altura dos links*/
.navbar::after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

/*adiciona bordar em baixo se o link estiver com foco ou tiver a classe*/
.navbar a:focus, .navbar a:hover, .navbar a.actived {
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Tweets</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

### Sobre a propriedade box-sizing

A propriedade é suportada pelos navegadores:

- Internet Explorer 8 ou superior
- Safari 3.1 até a versão 5 se usar o prefixo `-webkit-`
- Safari 5.1 ou superior sem necessidade do prefixo
- Android browser 2.1 até a versão 3 se usar o prefixo `-webkit-`
- BlackBerry 7 se usar o prefixo `-webkit-`
- O prefixo `-moz-` era somente necessário até a versão 28 do Firefox

Os valores suportados são:

- **content-box**

  **Este é o valor padrão**, conforme especificado pela norma CSS. As propriedades `width` (largura) e `height` (altura) são medidas incluindo só o conteúdo, mas não o `padding`, `border` ou `margin`. **Nota:** `padding`, `border` e `margin` serão fora da box, por exemplo.: Se `.box {width: 350px}` então se você aplicar uma propriedade `{border: 10px solid black;}` o resultado renderizado no navegador (browser) será `.box {width: 370px;}`
- **border-box**

  As propriedades de largura (`width`) e de altura (`height`) incluem o tamanho `padding` e a propriedade `border`, mas não incluem a propriedade `margin`.
- **padding-box**

  As propriedades de largura (`width`) e de altura (`height`) incluem o tamanho `padding`, mas não incluem a propriedade `border` e `margin`.

  > Este valor é suportado somente pelos navegadores baseados em Gecko, como o Firefox